# Hardware controlled RTS on a Pi4 not working accurately

Tags: raspbian, gpio, hardware, serial, python-3

We need to use RS485 to talk to one of our custom tools. We need to use hardware controlled rts/cts. I've read so many articles about this but nobody ever says it works for them with fast timing and hardware controlled.

However, I can't get it working, I think it is being software controlled still because our timings are really long. RTS may be **working** but its changing weird. We are seeing 250us before and after, but not the values we want of 3.5us before and 1us after.

Here is what I have done:

1. disabled and removed bluetooth completely.
2. modified `/boot/config.txt` to add the following:

```
enable_uart=1
init_uart_clock=16000000
gpu_mem=256
dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt
gpio=17=a3
dtoverlay=miniuart-ctsrts
```

I can then check to see that GPIO17 is in RTS0 mode:

```
root@raspberrypi:/# raspi-gpio get 17
GPIO 17: level=1 fsel=7 alt=3 func=RTS0
```

3. modified `boot/cmdline.txt` to the following:

```
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=7fa4337c-02 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait quiet splash plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles
```

4. ran this: https://github.com/mholling/rpirtscts
5. I am using PySerial and working with rs485 in this way [PySerial docs](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#rs485-support):

```
ser = serial.rs485.RS485(
     port='/dev/serial0', 
     baudrate=1000000, 
     timeout=0.1, 
     parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, 
     stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, 
     bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
     xonxoff = False,     #enable software flow control
     rtscts = True,     #enable hardware (RTS/CTS) flow control
     dsrdtr = True,       #disable hardware (DSR/DTR) flow control
     write_timeout=0.1
)

ser.rs485_mode = serial.rs485.RS485Settings(
     rts_level_for_tx=False, 
     rts_level_for_rx=True, 
     loopback=False, 
     delay_before_tx=0.0000035, 
     delay_before_rx=0.0000001
)
```

6. Here is my serial ports in `/dev`

```
root@raspberrypi:/dev# ls -al serial* ttyA*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          7 Sep 17 09:47 serial0 -> ttyAMA0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          5 Sep 17 09:47 serial1 -> ttyS0
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 204, 64 Sep 17 10:15 ttyAMA0
```

The caveat is that this could be working,but maybe not observing the delays we have in place. I don't know if the Pi 4 hardware is even capable of these very fast times. Looking on an oscilloscope, I can see data but it isn't stopping as quickly as I have specified so that leads me to believe that hardware control isn't working and I am in still in software controlled mode.

A few pictures:

[image: before data]
[image: after data]
[image: showing 1mb and 250us]

[image: setup]

Comment: Why not check the RTS line?  Surely the question will be different if RTS is being toggled properly?

Comment: @joan can you explain more what you mean?

Comment: You say RTS is not working.  RTS is a signal line connected to a GPIO and your hardware.  Have you checked it is being set properly?

Comment: @joan rts is "working" but its changing weird. We are seeing 250us before and after, but not the values we want of 3.5us before and 1us after.

Comment: That information needs to be edited into your question.  You also need to add supporting evidence such as a scope display.

Comment: is RPI UART capable of this rate though?

Comment: @abolotnov honestly, I'm not sure. I am posting a few pics now of what we are seeing.

Comment: If the longer delays work as you configure them, I'd assume the UART does not perform as fast as you want it to.

Comment: @abolotnov I uploaded a few pics that show the times before, time after, etc. We aren't seeing it obey the 3.5u before and 1.0u after that we want.